# How can I preload an image for a hover state to make the background change immediately, not after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, preloading

How could I preload an image for a hover state to make the background change immediately, not after a few seconds.i.e the Background must load before user hovers on a specific element.

The site can be viewed at http://www.paradisoperduto.co.uk/

I'm quite happy with the coding so far so was wondering if there was a relatively simple change to it to implement this. Many thanks.

```
<!-- background change -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hoverarea').hover(function() {
            $('body').addClass('hover');
        }, function(){
            $('body').removeClass('hover');
        });
      });
    </script>

        <!-- background change-->


    <div id="hoverarea"><a href="comingsoon.html"> <img src="images/blank.png" onmouseover="playSound('audio/apple2.mp3');"> </a></div>

body {
    background-image:url('../images/blackandwhite.gif');
    background-position:50% 20px; 
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color:black;
    height:714px;
    width:1024;
}

#hoverarea {
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    top:300px;
    right:20px;
    z-index:2000; 
}



.hover {
    background-image:url('../images/colour.gif');

}


li a:hover + img {
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Is an animated gif sprite possible though? See website link

Comment: It probably is, but animated gifs went out of style in the nineties, so I'm not sure ?

Comment: Animated gif sprites ARE possible though that would be a lot of work and result in a REALLY big file size for a web image. I'll take a look at your link again.

Comment: Ok, I looked at the link and I see what you're going for.  It looks like you're trying to have a flash-esque site without the flash. You're not really getting any of the benefits of ditching flash though because the gif isn't responsive. The problem you're running into is that you're trying to have two really big images pre-loaded before the user interacts with the page and that's just a fundamental problem. Not sure how you get around it with a site like the one you've set up.

Comment: gif is not responsive but it works on mobile if everyone forgot that Adobe doesn't support Flash for mobiles anymore. I'd probably use canvas - still my method would work as canvas can display only loaded images

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to the large background image.  The problem is, since you've got so few elements on the page, users will likely hover over the image even before the second one is pre-loaded.  It's a big image, after all.

One thing you can try is a CSS sprite. The concept there is that you combine your two images into one tall image so it all loads as one image. Then, in your css, you do something like this:

```
#hoverarea {
  background-image: url('../images/backgroundimage.gif');
  background-position: center top;
}

#hoverarea:hover {
  background-position: center bottom;
}
```

This way all you're doing is changing the css positioning of one image rather than using an arduous javascript solution to preload and inject a second image.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head there;a flash site without the flash!

Answer (score 0):

you can wait for this image in javascript - on my site I'm using 'cache lists' containint urls of pictures to be preloaded before website is displayed - if you'll make in js new Image element and give it src of this picture, when onload event will fire - browser will cache this image so it'll be displayed instantly when it'll appear in any other place. here is code from my website, but i guess it's clear how it works:

```
function cache(input, prefix, primary, cback){
  this.cback = cback
  this.tab=[];
  var tmp = input;
  var cur;
  for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
  {
    if (tmp[i][0] == primary)
      cur = i;
  }
  if (cur != undefined)
  {
    this.size = tmp[cur][1].length;
    if (this.size == 0)
      this.cback();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.size; i++)
    {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = prefix+tmp[cur][1][i];
      img.onload = this.imgReady.bind(this);
      img.onerror = this.imgError.bind(this);
      this.tab.push(img);
      console.log('caching:', img.src);
    }
    tmp.splice(cur, 1);
    return;
  }
  this.cback();
}

cache.prototype = {
  counter:0,
  size:0,
  tab:0,
  cback:function(){return;},
  imgReady:function(element){
    this.counter++;
    if (this.counter == this.size){
      storeCache(this.tab)
      this.cback(this.tab);
    }},
  imgError:function(){
    DEBUG.innerHTML+='[ERROR] cache error!<br>';
    console.log('cache error...');
    this.imgReady();}
}
```

and cache list looks like:

```
[
  [
    'main',
    [
      '/pictures/party.png',
      '/pictures/icon.png',
      '/pictures/+1.png',
      '/pictures/splash.jpeg',
      '/pictures/logo_compact.png',
      '/pictures/dj.png',
      '/pictures/sign.png',
      '/textures/main.jpg',
      '/textures/shadow.png',
      '/textures/smallshadow.png',
      '/textures/outlineH.png',
      '/textures/outlineV.png',
      '/textures/bg.jpg',
      '/textures/alt.jpg'
    ]
  ],
  [
    'theme_selector',
    [
      '/../uni/p1.png',
      '/../uni/p1a.png',
      '/../uni/p2.png',
      '/../uni/p2a.png',
      '/../uni/p3.png',
      '/../uni/p3a.png',
    ]
  ],
  ...
]
```

actually I'm using one cache file for all subsites that's why there are 'main', or 'theme_selector' identifiers in cache list (they're passed as prefix argument)

So general idea is to create image element for each important picture and continue actions after all of them will fire onload event (or onerror) because then they'll be already cached by browser and displayed instantly everywhere we want

Comment: Great stuff! I'll try the first gents soloution first as seems easier to my non web person brain but thanks a lot!

Comment: if you want to use exactly my code - put all images to one category eg. 'mane' and pass : as first argument this **cache array**, as second your **root path** (eg. in my case 'http: //localhost/style/pictures'), as third **category name**, so 'mane' or something else if you'd like to use this categories system, and callback function as last argument